# Middle-aligned option without width argument for tabular using array package

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, arrays

Consider a basic `tabular` environment.  Two columns, the first must contain a `tikzpicture` of indeterminate size, the second, a description of determinate (and user-specified) width.  If the content of the first column was well-constrained, one could do this:

```
\begin{tabular}{m{2cm}p{6cm}}
```

The content of the first column is not, however, well-constrained and so I wonder whether we can achieve the equivalent of this:

```
\begin{tabular}{mp{6cm}}
```

or

```
\begin{tabular}{m{}p{6cm}}
```

Middle-aligned first column, yet with no width argument.  I'll post an mwe if clarity is needed.

Comment: Did you try with an ordinary specifier and `\includegraphic{valign=c}{tikzpicture}`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the desired horizontal alignment of the first column you can simply chose `l`(left aligned), `c`(horizontally centered)  or `r` (right aligned) for the first column. This will automatically adapt to the width of the included tikzpicture. In order to vertically center the text in the second column with respect to the tikzpicture, use `m{6cm}` for the second column and add `baseline=(current bounding box.center)` as an option to each tikzpicture.

Since this setup might lead to a table that is wider than the textwidth, you might also want to give `tabularx` a try. I have also included a `tabularx` example in the following MWE. Please note that I used `\hline` as a guide to the eye. In the actual table I wouldn't use `\hline` but lines from the `booktabs` package or no horizontal lines at all:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{cm{6cm}}
\hline
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.center)] 
\node[draw=black] (text1) {some text here};
\node[draw=black] (text2) [below left =of text1] {some other text here}edge [->] node {}(text1) ;
\end{tikzpicture}
& some explanatory text that is vertically centered with respect to the tikz picture\\
\hline
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.center)] 
\node[draw=black] (text1) {A};
\node[draw=black] (text2) [below left =of text1] {B}edge [->] node {}(text1) ;
\end{tikzpicture}
& some explanatory text that is vertically centered with respect to the tikz picture\\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{cX}
\hline
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.center)] 
\node[draw=black] (text1) {some text here};
\node[draw=black] (text2) [below left =of text1] {some other text here}edge [->] node {}(text1) ;
\end{tikzpicture}
& some explanatory text that is vertically centered with respect to the tikz picture\\
\hline
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.center)] 
\node[draw=black] (text1) {A};
\node[draw=black] (text2) [below left =of text1] {B}edge [->] node {}(text1) ;
\end{tikzpicture}
& some explanatory text that is vertically centered with respect to the tikz picture\\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Super elegant.  The `baseline=(current bounding box.center)` option to the `tikzpicture` did the trick.